# How can we install just cqlsh (just CLI) on RHEL instead of complete cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, installation, rhel, cqlsh

How can we install cqlsh on RHEL (not the complete cassandra setup) ?

I have tried installing the complete Cassandra
https://docs.nomagic.com/display/TWCloud190/Installing+and+configuring+Cassandra+on+Linux#InstallingandconfiguringCassandraonLinux-installCassOfflineInstallingCassandraoffline

but I need only cqlsh.

cqlsh installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install it via `pip`:

```sh
pip install cqlsh
```

[See propject at pypi](https://pypi.org/project/cqlsh/).

Comment: Thanks Alex! It works perfect on a machine where I have internet. But it is getting really difficult when I have to install it on a system where I dont have internet. is there any short way to install it on a disconnected machine ?

Comment: You need to download all dependencies, etc. Here is the article on how to do it: https://www.nyayapati.com/srao/2014/06/how-to-pip-install-python-packages-offline/

Comment: Resolved the issue. The problem was I did not had internet on my network. But fortunately found a local pip repo that solved the whole problem.

Answer (score -1):

No way of doing this as far as I know. Would love to have cqlsh client-only program.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that you want/need a tool which can help you to execute CQL statements against one or more Cassandra clusters; if that is the case, if you are using Datastax's version of the Cassandra engine, or Datastax Enterprise, you should be able to use [Datastax Studio](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-studio-and-development-tools#DataStax-Studio), which will allow you to execute statements and model the schema to use.

Looking for other options, there is [Hackolade](https://hackolade.com/nosqldb/cassandra-data-modeling.html) that will allow you to also do data modeling, or [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/2018/05/27/dbeaver-5-0-6/) which offers a Cassandra driver to interact with the clusters.

Comment: Thanks Carlos for the quick response!  I am looking for a CLI tool in order to execute cassandra queries on a Cassandra DB. What I understood by googling a little about the tools you mentioned that they all are GUI based only and not sure are how much compatible with RHEL.